# Display files with syntax highlighting using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on a web based application using php (not using Java), in which I am required to display source code files (java,c,c++,Python etc..) with syntax highlighting on the web page. I am clueless on as to how to display the source code files. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options is use a existing [syntax highlighter like a google one](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).

Setting it up is very simple. All you have to do for [basic usage](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Usage) is include the code in your html page in `<pre>` sections and apply a class attribute that is programming language.

```
<pre name="code" class="c-sharp">
class Foo
{
}
</pre>
```

**[16 Free Javascript Code Syntax Highlighters For Better Programming](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/)** has a very exhaustive list of lot of options. repeated here in case the site ever goes down

1. [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
2. [GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php)
3. [quickhighlighter](http://quickhighlighter.com/)
4. [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
5. [pygments](http://pygments.org/).
6. [HIGHLIGHT.JS](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)
7. [Lighter.js – Syntax Highlighter written in MooTools](https://github.com/pradador/Lighter/)
8. [SHJS – Syntax Highlighting in JavaScript](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)
9. [CodePress – Online Real Time Syntax Highlighting Editor](http://codepress.sourceforge.net/index.php)
10. [Chili jQuery code highlighter plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/)
11. [Highlight – Code & Syntax highlighting by Andre Simon](http://www.andre-simon.de/index.html)
12. [BeautyOfCode: jQuery Plugin for Syntax Highlighting](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/)
13. [JUSH – JavaScript Syntax Highlighter](http://jush.sourceforge.net/)
14. [Ultraviolet – Syntax Highlighting Engine](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=3513)
15. [DlHighlight – JavaScript Syntax Highlighting Engine](http://mihai.bazon.net/projects/javascript-syntax-highlighting-engine#Similar%20projects)
16. [Syntax highlighter for JavaScript](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/syntax/)

Comment: Are there any API's avilable?

Comment: You don't need any apis... Do you want to process the syntax on server side ?

Comment: @PaulDC What exactly is the API that you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlighter is used to show the source code program is colorful, so the reader can easily read/understand your code after integration. In this program, I added various elements (reserve words, parenthesis, comment, and quotes etc..) for highlighting. You can add/modify this code based on your Web Application/Programming Blog.

This syntax highlighter code is independent to any language, so you add integration with any programming language.

Please find the source code from my tech blog - http://www.algonuts.info/how-to-develop-a-source-code-syntax-highlighter-using-php.html

```
<?php
include_once("keywords.php");
class highlighter {

    private $fileName;
    private $fileNameColor;
    private $fileExtension;
    private $parenthesisColor;
    private $insideParenthesisColor;
    private $keywordColor;
    private $backGroundColor;
    private $borderColor;
    private $leftBorderColor;
    private $quotesColor;
    private $commentColor;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->fileName = "";

        $this->fileExtension = "";

        //Color Configuration
        $this->fileNameColor = "#286090";
        $this->keywordColor = "green";
        $this->backGroundColor = "#fdfefe";

        $this->borderColor = "#e3e3e3";
        $this->leftBorderColor = "#605a56";

        $this->parenthesisColor = "#ec7700";
        $this->insideParenthesisColor = "#ec7700";
        $this->bracketColor = "#ec7700";
        $this->insideBracketColor = "#ec7700";

        $this->quotesColor = "#6a2c70";
        $this->commentColor = "#b8b0b0";
    }

    public function applycolor($fileLocation = "") {
        if($fileLocation == "")
        {   return; }
        else
        {
            if(file_exists($fileLocation)) {
                $temp = explode("/",$fileLocation);
                $this->fileName = trim(end($temp));
                $temp = explode(".",$this->fileName);
                $this->fileExtension = trim(end($temp));
                $fileContent = trim(file_get_contents($fileLocation, true));
                $fileContent = htmlentities($fileContent,ENT_NOQUOTES);
                if($fileContent == "")
                {   return; }
            }
            else
            {   return; }
        }

        $line = 1;
        $outputContent = "<div class=\"divblock\"><b>".$line."</b>  ";
        $characterBuffer = "";

        $blockFound = 0;
        $blockFoundColor = array();
        $parenthesisFound = 0;
        $bracketFound = 0;

        $counter = 0;
        $lastCharacter = "";
        $contentSize = strlen($fileContent);                    

        while($counter < $contentSize) {
            $character = $fileContent[$counter];
            $code = intval(ord($character));
            if($blockFound == 0 && (($code >= 97 && $code <= 122) || ($code >= 65 && $code <= 90))) //Fnd alphabetic characters
            {   $characterBuffer .= $character; }
            else
            {
                if($code == 10) { //Find EOL (End of Line)
                    if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                    {   $characterBuffer = "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>"; }
                    $line++;
                    if($blockFound == 0)
                    { $outputContent .= $characterBuffer."</div>".$character."<div class=\"divblock\"><b>".$line."</b>  "; }
                    else
                    { $outputContent .= $characterBuffer."</font></div>".$character."<div class=\"divblock\"><b>".$line."</b>  <font color='".$blockFoundColor[$blockFound-1]."'>"; }
                    $characterBuffer = "";
                }
                else if($code == 32) {  //Find Space
                    if($characterBuffer != "") {
                        if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                        {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>".$character;   }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer.$character;  }
                        $characterBuffer = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {   $outputContent .= $character;   }
                }
                else if($character == "\"" || $character == "'") {  //Find Quotes
                    if($characterBuffer != "")
                    {
                        if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                        {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>";  }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer; }
                        $characterBuffer = "";
                    }
                    $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->quotesColor."'>".$character;
                    $foundCharacter = $character;
                    $counter++;
                    while($counter < $contentSize) {
                        $character = $fileContent[$counter];
                        if($character == $foundCharacter) {
                            $outputContent .= $character;
                            if($lastCharacter == "\\") {
                                $lastCharacter = "";
                            }
                            else
                            {   break;  }
                        }
                        else if($character == "\\" && $lastCharacter == "\\") {
                            $outputContent .= $character;
                            $lastCharacter = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $lastCharacter = $character;
                            $code = intval(ord($character));
                            if($code != 10) 
                            {   $outputContent .= $character;   }
                            else
                            {   
                                $line++;
                                $outputContent .= "</font></div>".$character."<div class=\"divblock\"><b>".$line."</b>  <font color='".$this->quotesColor."'>";     
                            }
                        }
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    $outputContent .= "</font>";
                }
                else if($character == "(" || $character == ")") {   //Find Parenthesis
                    if($characterBuffer != "")
                    {
                        if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                        {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>";  }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer; }
                        $characterBuffer = "";
                    }
                    if($parenthesisFound == 0) {
                        $blockFoundColor[$blockFound] = $this->insideParenthesisColor;
                        $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->parenthesisColor."'>".$character."</font><font color='".$this->insideParenthesisColor."'>";
                        $parenthesisFound++;
                        $blockFound++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if($character == "(") {
                            $parenthesisFound++;
                        }
                        if($character == ")") {
                            $parenthesisFound--;
                        }
                        if($parenthesisFound == 0) {
                            $outputContent .= "</font><font color='".$this->parenthesisColor."'>".$character."</font>";
                            $blockFound--;
                            unset($blockFoundColor[$blockFound]);
                        }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $character;   }
                    }
                }
                else if($character == "[" || $character == "]") {   //Find Bracket
                    if($characterBuffer != "")
                    {
                        if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                        {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>";  }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer; }
                        $characterBuffer = "";
                    }
                    if($bracketFound == 0) {
                        $blockFoundColor[$blockFound] = $this->insideBracketColor;
                        $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->bracketColor."'>".$character."</font><font color='".$this->insideBracketColor."'>";
                        $bracketFound++;
                        $blockFound++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if($character == "[") {
                            $bracketFound++;
                        }
                        if($character == "]") {
                            $bracketFound--;
                        }
                        if($bracketFound == 0) {
                            $outputContent .= "</font><font color='".$this->bracketColor."'>".$character."</font>";
                            $blockFound--;
                            unset($blockFoundColor[$blockFound]);
                        }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $character;   }
                    }
                }
                else if($character == "/" && (isset($fileContent[$counter+1]) && ($fileContent[$counter+1] == "*" || $fileContent[$counter+1] == "/"))) {   //Find Comment
                    if($characterBuffer != "")
                    {
                        if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                        {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>";  }
                        else
                        {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer; }
                        $characterBuffer = "";
                    }
                    $blockFound++;
                    $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->commentColor."'>".$fileContent[$counter].$fileContent[$counter+1];
                    if($fileContent[$counter+1] == "*") {
                        $counter += 2;
                        $checkCharacter = "*";
                        while($counter < $contentSize) {
                            $outputContent .= $fileContent[$counter];
                            if($fileContent[$counter] == $checkCharacter) {
                                if($checkCharacter == "*") 
                                {   $checkCharacter = "/";  }
                                else 
                                {
                                    $blockFound--;
                                    $outputContent .= "</font>";
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            $counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $counter += 2;
                        while($counter < $contentSize) {
                            $character = $fileContent[$counter];
                            $code = intval(ord($character));
                            if($code == 10) {
                                $counter--;
                                $blockFound--;
                                $outputContent .= "</font>";
                                break;
                            }
                            $outputContent .= $character;
                            $counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if($characterBuffer != "")
                {
                    if($this->checker($characterBuffer))                
                    {   $outputContent .= "<font color='".$this->keywordColor."'>".$characterBuffer."</font>".$character;   }
                    else
                    {   $outputContent .= $characterBuffer.$character;  }
                    $characterBuffer = "";
                }
                else
                {   $outputContent .= $character;   }
            }
            $counter++;
        }
        $outputContent .= "</div>";

        $rerurnData = "<div class='filenamestyle' style='color:".$this->fileNameColor.";'>".$this->fileName."</div>";   //Show filename
        $rerurnData .= "<div><pre><div class='codebox' style='background-color:".$this->backGroundColor.";border: 1px solid ".$this->borderColor.";border-left: 4px solid ".$this->leftBorderColor.";'>".$outputContent."</div></pre></div>";
        return $rerurnData;
    }

    private function checker($value) {
        global $languageKeywords;       
        if(isset($languageKeywords[$this->fileExtension])) {                
            $value = trim($value);
            if(in_array($value,$languageKeywords[$this->fileExtension]))
            {   return 1;   }
            else
            {   return 0;   }
        }       
    }
}
?>
```